# How to show a banner using a Chrome extension which doesn't require DOM modification

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In Firefox, [Certificate Patrol](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/certificate-patrol/) addon displays a warning on the top of the page you are visiting like this:

[image: Firefox warning]

How can I create a similar thing using a Chrome extension?

I like that it is separate from the website content (its DOM). Is this possible in Chrome or should I inject DOM into the page itself? But then the page can interfere with it?

Alternatively, is there some other more Chrome-like way to display warnings (imagine security issues)? I would not like to block the site (so that user can see what is happening) but display some message. The way how Firefox does it really looks great and the proper way as pages can't manipulate it in any way.

Comment: use javascript because that's what chrome extensions are written with

Comment: These bars were considered before but it never made into the release channel.

Comment: Is there a workaround? Or some other more "Chromy" approach?

Comment: Do you by any chance have an example of an actual Chrome extension (by whoever), that does the same? Because your question shows an FF example and asks for a CH equivalent... Because if there's none, then maybe just maybe it's not possible to display chrome-only content...

Comment: No, if I would have an example from Chrome, then I would look into its code to see how it is done. But if there is no answer to this question, then the question is not too broad, no?

Comment: @JaromandaX: OP didn't ask what to use to accomplish what they want but **how to do it** as this is far from being a trivial question... And got closed prematurely. These kind of questions are actually the basis of why SO is so great.

Comment: **I think this question should be reopened as it's very specific and targets Crome extension development community**. All those that voted for it to be closed I ask to reconsider reopening...

Comment: @Derek: Any link to your claims? It would help get a proper answer.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Back in the early days in developing the Chrome APIs there was an experimental API called [`chrome.infobars`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/infobars). However they stayed as experimental for some time and later finally removed.

Comment: This question is currently being [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315304/can-my-question-please-be-reopened?noredirect=1)

Comment: @RobertKoritnik if you feel that strongly about keeping the question open, may I suggest you make your case on the [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315304/can-my-question-please-be-reopened?noredirect=1) I previously linked.  A strong argument about why it isn't too broad may help keep the question open.

Comment: How can it be both too broad at the same time and there seems to be no way to achieve it (the only way is chrome.infobars which were deprecated)?

Comment: @derek I think your comment has enough valuable information that it can be an answer. Sometimes unfortunately the right answer is the one saying *can't be done*.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Added a proper answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to display a bar on top without modifying the active tab's DOM. There was an API ([experimental until it got removed](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=359136#c6)), namely `chrome.infobars` ([cache of documentation in 2011](http://www.adambarth.com/experimental/crx/docs/experimental.infobars.html)) which does the exact thing that you wanted, however Chrome has since moved away from these bars, and possibly does not encourage the use of these bars.

Remember these bars?

[image]

[They are long gone.](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/Asv3vsDmVIY) The people who worked on Chrome has decided to remove all traces of these bars and replaced them with page actions.

---

If you really need these bars, you will have to find the active tab, and inject a small HTML section to display the bar. To semi-separate it from the page, you can inject an `iframe` so the styles don't interfere with each other. But keep in mind that, the preferred way would be to use a [page action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) instead, ie display an icon in the omnibar (address bar) when you need user's attention.

Comment: Hm, but I would have to display a big warning. Page action seems a bit too ... small. Is there a way to hook into security notifications (those which ask for location and mic and other permissions)?

Comment: @Mitar Unfortunately no. But you can however display a notification to the user.

Comment: Would you display a SSL error in a notification? You probably would not. ;-) Me neither. :-) But thanks for the answer. I will try to find some other way. Maybe I can redirect the whole page to an extension URL with an error message and then embed the original page inside as an sandboxed iframe for user to see about which page the error is about.